# How can I make my java program not create multiple instances when calling the constructor with parameters?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a homework assignment that provides a GUI interface and displays ten teams, each represented by a button. Each button has a radio button to the left of it that allows the user to select the radio and then click another teams button to move the selected team to that position. The selected team will move and the other teams will shift either up or down.

This is not the issue. The code is complete but, I have a problem. Currently it works but after each click of a button the program makes a new call to the constructor which then opens another instance of the program, but the data shifts correctly.

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to make this work. I tried to make it call the method that creates the GUI but it doesn't work properly and throws a nasty exception.

My code is below and the area of concern is line 99 and 100. Line 99 is commented out. It is what I tried instead of the new constructor call on line 100.

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Note: (I'm not looking for someone to complete my homework for me. I have completed this code from scratch and I have exhausted myself trying to figure this thing out. Thanks!)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class P03TopTenTeams extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] teams = {"Texas", "Vanderbilt", "Florida", "Missouri","Arkansas",            "Kentucky", "Alabama", "Tennessee", "Georgia","Louisiana"};
    new P03TopTenTeams(teams);
}

private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;
private JButton[] btn = new JButton[10];
private JRadioButton[] rbtn = new JRadioButton[10];
private ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup();
private ButtonGroup bg2 = new ButtonGroup();

public P03TopTenTeams(String[] teams) {
    buildWindow(teams);
}
private void buildWindow(String[] teams) {
    int index;
    this.setSize(300, 500);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setTitle("Top Ten Teams");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        rbtn[index] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton(
                Integer.toString(index + 1));
        bg1.add(rbtn[index]);
        panel1.add(rbtn[index]);
    }
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
    BtnHdlr btnhdlr = new BtnHdlr();
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        btn[index] = new javax.swing.JButton(teams[index]);
        bg2.add(btn[index]);
        panel2.add(btn[index]);
        btn[index].addActionListener(btnhdlr);
    }

    this.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
private class BtnHdlr implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int from = 0;
        int to = 0;
        String[] teams = new String[10];
        int index;

        for (index = 0; index < bg1.getButtonCount(); index++) {
            teams[index] = btn[index].getText();
            if (rbtn[index].isSelected() == true) {
                from = index;
            }
            if (btn[index].getText().equals(event.getActionCommand()))   {
                to = index;
            }
        }

        updateTeamsArray(teams, from, to);

    }
}
private void updateTeamsArray(String[] teams, int from, int to) {
    int index;

    String valueFrom = teams[from];

    if (from < to) {
        for (index = from; index < to; index++) {
            teams[index] = teams[index + 1];
        }
        teams[to] = valueFrom;
    } else {
        for (index = from; index > to; index--) {
            teams[index] = teams[index - 1];
        }
        teams[to] = valueFrom;
    }
     //buildWindow(teams);
    new P03TopTenTeams(teams);

}
}
```

Comment: You want to create instance only once and return the same instance afterwards if you require?

Comment: After each button click I would like for the panel to refresh with the buttons rearranged to the new order of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems insanely obvious: if you don't want the constructor called, **don't call it**! Simply get the constructor call out of your updateTeamsArray method.

More specifically:

- Remove all buttons from the container that holds them
- Re-add the buttons to that container in the new order
- Call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container.
- Or more simply, you can simply rename your JButtons with the array names in the new order.

For example:

```
private void updateTeamsArray(String[] teams, int from, int to) {
  int index;

  String valueFrom = teams[from];

  if (from < to) {
     for (index = from; index < to; index++) {
        teams[index] = teams[index + 1];
     }
     teams[to] = valueFrom;
  } else {
     for (index = from; index > to; index--) {
        teams[index] = teams[index - 1];
     }
     teams[to] = valueFrom;
  }

  // buildWindow(teams);
  // new P03TopTenTeams(teams);  // delete this!

  // ***** add this *****
  for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
     btn[i].setText(teams[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. I tried the method call that is commented out directly above it. It doesn't refresh the panel like I thought it would. Just crashes.

Comment: @billabrian6: see last suggestion for easiest solution.

Comment: I think the remove/re-add solution would be reasonable as well.  The structure of the code from there is straightforward.  You initialize and configure the jFrame once (in the constructor?), and the all the code that builds the buttons goes into a method.  You just write this method to accept the `teams` String array, so that you can pass a re-ordered version after swaps occur.  Then add code to the button handler to remove any buttons that exist and you should be set.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the help. It always seems to be that little things that get me. BTW, Is it possible to remove my code? I would hate for a classmate to stumble upon it and use it.

Comment: @billabrian6: Please don't delete any of your code or your question. Your question is not just for your immediate benefit only, but more importantly, it's for the benefit of those in the future with similar problems. If you delete pertinent information, the question and answers will be useless to the future folks. Also, if you received help on this site, then your class-mates have a right to benefit from the same help. Finally, if you delete your code or question, many on this site will lose respect for you for the above reasons.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I see. Just worried about it being plagiarized. My professor claims he had a problem in the past with it. Anyways, Do you feel like I stated my problem well enough? Or could it use some work?

Comment: @billabrian6: it seems fine to me. Next time, I suggest that you create a new program that is similar to but not the same as your assignment program, that is simpler than the assignment program, but that demonstrates your immediate problem and nothing else. In other words *extract* your problem out of your program and put it in its own very simple compilable and runnable program. That way we can study a simpler smaller program, will be able to understand your issues quicker and help you better, and you won't have to worry about plagiarism.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Thanks very much. I will keep this in mind for the future. Have a nice day!